# Getting list of Radisonde Stations Codes and ID Number in Python-Siphon

Tags: python-siphon

I'm looking to bulk download a lot of individual Radisonde datasets for North and South America to do some analysis on.  Is there a way to retrieve all the station names and id numbers for the whole region to loop through without manually looking all of them up and making my own dataset or csv file with a list of all of them?

Thanks,
Tristan